# Reorder columns in dynamic SQL PIVOT

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot

I am pivoting rows into columns using Dynamic SQL in order to account for an unknown number of columns.
I am using SQL Server 16

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PatientDiagnosis) 
                from
                (
                  select 'Diagnosis'
                          + cast(row_number() over(partition by LbPatientId
                                                    order by LbPatientId) as varchar(10)) PatientDiagnosis
                  from #Diag50
                  --ORDER  BY ',' + Quotename(PatientDiagnosis) DESC
                ) d
                group by PatientDiagnosis
                 ORDER  BY ',' + Quotename(PatientDiagnosis)                    
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT LbPatientId, ' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (
            select LbPatientId, Diagnosis,
              ''Diagnosis''
                + cast(row_number() over(partition by LbPatientId
                                          order by LbPatientId) as varchar(10)) PatientDiagnosis
            from #Diag50
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            MIN(Diagnosis)
            for PatientDiagnosis in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

This does pivot my data but the sort order for the Diagnosis columns is wrong.

It looks like this (there may be up to 50 columns for each LbPatientId)

```
LbPatientId|Diagnosis1|Diagnosis10|Diagnosis11|Diagnosis12...
```

-----------|----------|-----------|-----------|--------------
1111       |Z95.5     |Z23        |Z13.89     |V85.1

I want it to look like this:

```
LbPatientId|Diagnosis1|Diagnosis2 |Diagnosis3 |Diagnosis4..
```

-----------|----------|-----------|-----------|--------------
1111       |Z95.5     |Z23        |Z13.89

I've tried various solutions I found for ordering columns, but it's still not working.  It's really the column headings that are important here as far as order goes.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its because it is ordering alphabetically due to RowNumber being concatenated with 'Diagnosis' you want to order it numerically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the row_number in your query and order by that instead.

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PatientDiagnosis) 
                from
                (
                  select 'Diagnosis'
                          + cast(row_number() over(partition by LbPatientId
                                                    order by LbPatientId) as varchar(10)) PatientDiagnosis,
                          row_number() over(partition by LbPatientId
                                                    order by LbPatientId)  PatientDiagnosisOrder
                  from #Diag50
                ) d
                group by PatientDiagnosis, PatientDiagnosisOrder
                ORDER  BY PatientDiagnosisOrder                    
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```